# Run typed_test for only one of specified types

Tags: c++, googletest

Let's suppose i've written a code like this.

```
template <typename T>
  class FooTest : public testing::Test
  {
     //class body
  };
  typedef ::testing::Types<int, float/*, and few more*/> TestTypes;
  TYPED_TEST_CASE(FooTest, TestTypes);


  TYPED_TEST(FooTest, test1)
  {
     //...
  }
  TYPED_TEST(FooTest, test2)
  {
     //...;
  }
```

Is there any possibility to run, for example second test, for **only one** of data types specified in *TestTypes* and avoid any code duplication?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this by creating a second test class using inheiritance.

This is similar to the approaches on two faq entries:

[Can I derive a test fixture from another?](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_6_FAQ#Can_I_derive_a_test_fixture_from_another?)

[I have several test cases which share the same logic...](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_6_FAQ#I_have_several_test_cases_which_share_the_same_test_fixture_logi)

In the code outline below, I have separate the types into two *disjoint* sets.

```
  template <typename T>
  class FooTest : public testing::Test
  {
     //class body
  };

  // TestTypes only contains some of the types as before
  // in this example, floating point types are tested only with FooTest.
  typedef ::testing::Types<float, double, /*, and few more*/> TestTypes;

  TYPED_TEST_CASE(FooTest, TestTypes);

  TYPED_TEST(FooTest, test1)
  {
     //...
  }

  // Optional, but could allow you to reuse test constructor 
  // and SetUp/TearDown functions
  template <typename T>
  class ExtendedFooTest : public FooTest<T>
  {}

  // And integral types are given extended tests
  typedef ::testing::Types<int, unsigned int, and few more*/> ExtendedFooTypes;

  TYPED_TEST_CASE(FooTest, ExtendedFooTypes);         // repeat the tests above
  TYPED_TEST_CASE(ExtendedFooTest, ExtendedFooTypes); // Plus add new tests.

  TYPED_TEST(ExtendedFooTest, test2)
  {
     //...;
  }
```